# Updating a field using if/elif

Tags: arcpy

Edited Question:

My question concerns using arcpy to add a field to an existing feature class attribute table. I am populating a Freq_Rating field using values from a Fire_Frequency field. The Fire_frequency field shows the frequency of Wildfire start points identified within a WRIA Basin (Watershed Resource Inventory Area). I completed the first part of the code successfully and then added the field for Freq_Rating to the attribute table. It's a text field where I separate the Frequency values into four distinct classes; no fire history, low, moderate and high. When I run the script the values all show up as Null.

Question: Why are my values showing up as Null? Where is the error in my script?

```py
#First part of the script (for context, go to next hashtag to see problem area) 

import arcpy
import os

try:
  arcpy.env.workspace=r"D:\423_ArcPy\Final_Project\Kiendl_423_FinalProject.gdb"
  GDB=r"D:\423_ArcPy\Final_Project\Kiendl_423_FinalProject.gdb"
  watersheds= "WRIA_Basins"
  fires= "WA_Fire_Points"
  print ("Feature classes have been defined.")
  arcpy.env.overwriteOutput= True
  print ("Commence Identity and Frequency tool use.")
  Ident_Output= fires+"identity"
  arcpy.analysis.Identity (fires, watersheds, Ident_Output, "","","")
  Freq_Outable= fires+ "frequency"
  arcpy.analysis.Frequency(Ident_Output, Freq_Outable, "WRIA_NM","")
  print ("Create Frequency dictionary.")
  Freq_Dict= {}  
  inputfc=os.path.join(GDB,watersheds)
  inputfq=os.path.join(GDB,Freq_Outable)
  with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (inputfq, ["WRIA_NM", "FREQUENCY"]) as scursors:
    for field in scursors:
      if field[0]:
        Freq_Dict[field[0]]=field[1]
      else:
        pass
 
  print ("Fire Frequency Dictionary created, keys and values have been populated.")
  print (Freq_Dict.items())
  arcpy.management.AddField(watersheds,"Fire_Frequency","LONG")
  print("Fire frequency field is added to WRIA_Basins Feature Class.") 
  with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (watersheds,["WRIA_NM", "Fire_Frequency"]) as ucursor:
    for field in ucursor:
     WRIA_NM= field[0]
     if WRIA_NM in Freq_Dict:
        field [1]= Freq_Dict[WRIA_NM]
     else:
        field[1]=0
     ucursor.updateRow(field)
  print ("Update Field is completed.")
  arcpy.management.AddField(watersheds,"Freq_Rating","TEXT")
  print ("Freq_Rating Field created.")


#The problematic portion is listed below:


  FCS = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
  firefields = ['Fire_Frequency', 'Freq_Rating']
  #                   0                  1
  for FC in FCS:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (FC, firefields)as upcursor:
      if FC== "WRIA_basins":
        for row in upcursor:
          if (row [0] >= 1 and row [0] <= 200): row [1]="Low"
          elif (row [0] > 201 and row [0] <= 500): row [1]= "Moderate"
          elif (row [0] > 501 and row [0] <= 1373): row [1]= "High"
          elif (row [0] == 0): row [1]= "No Fire" 
          else:
            pass 
          upcursor.updateRow()
  print ("Freq_Rating values have been added.")
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Below is a screen shot of the attribute table to confirm the fire_frequency table was indeed populated:

[image]

Comment: Where did you define `row`?

Comment: Could you please include a focused question within the body of text? Also, please add formatted text rather than a screenshot. This helps us copy and paste to help troubleshoot and also helps with searches for other users.

Comment: Can you please confirm that your `Fire_Frequency` field in your `watersheds` FC  (WRIA_basins) correctly populated with numeric values?

Comment: faith_dur I added a screenshot of the attribute table, the first values show area all areas with 0 for fire frequency, and you can see at the end there the frequency numbers are populating correctly for WRIA basins with fire point data in the boundary (very low numbers, but all records are correctly populated).

Comment: Can you add a simple example of what you are trying to do. You are trying to calculate the 'Freq_rating' field? How? If fire_frequency is ?? then rating should be ??

Comment: The current code is far too large and has all-encompasing `try` block. Looping a list with an `if` constraint is awful flow of control. Best practice is to indent the `if` / `elif` code on the line following the colon (that would also permit diagnostic `print` statements). You can choose any indent scheme you want, so long as you want four spaces -- see PEP8. And you need to follow the accessor syntax, passing in the changed row in `updateRow`.

Answer (score 2):

Since [fatih_dur](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28687/fatih-dur) may have already answered the ArcPy aspect of the question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/432819/196564) , I will focus on Python issues and comments.

Looking at the `elif` logic, the values `201` and `501` will not get a rating.

```py
>>> def elif_logic(value):
...     if (value >= 1 and value <= 200): return "Low"
...     elif (value > 201 and value <= 500): return "Moderate"
...     elif (value > 501 and value <= 1373): return "High"
...     elif (value == 0): return "No Fire"
...     else:
...         return "No rating will be given"
...
>>>
>>> print(*(f"{i},{elif_logic(i)}" for i in (0,1,200,201,202,500,501,502)), sep="\n")
0,No Fire
1,Low
200,Low
201,Missing rating
202,Moderate
500,Moderate
501,Missing rating
502,High
>>>
```

I point this out since I assume those values should get ratings too.

When reclassifying values based on contiguous ranges, the Python [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) module offers an alternative to else-if blocks.

```py
>>> def bisect_logic(value):
...     import bisect
...
...     freq_breaks = (0,1,201,501,1374)
...     freq_ratings = (None, "No Fire", "Low", "Moderate", "High", None)
...     return freq_ratings[bisect.bisect(freq_breaks, value)]
...
>>>
>>> print(*(f"{i},{bisect_logic(i)}" for i in (0,1,200,201,202,500,501,502)), sep="\n")
0,No Fire
1,Low
200,Low
201,Moderate
202,Moderate
500,Moderate
501,High
502,High
>>>
```

In this case, I am not sure `bisect` adds any value sine the reclassification depends on 4 categories, but it can make a difference when more categories are involved.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you need to tell update cursor which object to update. In this case, you need to revise your last line as

`upcursor.updateRow(row)`

In any case, I would suggest below as the last bit of your code:

```
for FC in FCS:
    if FC == watersheds:
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (FC, firefields)as upcursor:
            for row in upcursor:
                if (row[0] == 0): row [1]= "No Fire"
                elif (row[0] >= 1 and row[0] <= 200): row [1]="Low"
                elif (row[0] > 201 and row[0] <= 500): row [1]= "Moderate"
                elif (row[0] > 501 and row[0] <= 1373): row [1]= "High"                
                else:
                    continue 
                upcursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: faith_dur your my hero!  That code worked! So to recap: I should have specified what FC represents before I assigned the UpdateCursor to sort/update the records for firefields?  And ended the else statement with continue instead of pass, so the iteration doesn't miss any records in the updatecursor?

Comment: You are iterating the `row` object, so you need to tell your cursor which object will update your row. `updateRow` is a method of the cursor and you need to explicitly specify with which you want to update. For example, in your case, you can create a list of `[0, 'No Fire']` for 0 case and say `upcursor.updateRow([0, 'No Fire'])`. The use of `pass` is not suitable here because if the value of your row value does not satisfy the condition(s), you want to skip it, instead of overwriting the row. `continue` silently moves to the next iteration.